# Можно ли получить цепочку прототипов объекта в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли получить цепочку прототипов объекта в JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Для этого существует метод [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
function getPrototypesChain(obj) {
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    if (null === proto) {
        return [];
    }

    return [proto].concat(getPrototypesChain(proto));
}

console.log(getPrototypesChain({}));
```